# jQuery#selector: filtering/tupling by different/unique class names

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that I have the following data:

```
<div class="menu row1"></div>
<div class="menu row1"></div>
<div class="menu row1"></div>
<div class="menu row2"></div>
<div class="menu row2"></div>
<div class="menu row3"></div>
```

and I want to select all the div elements that contains the "menu" class, but filtered by it's second class name (row1, row2 & row3).

Ej:

```
jQuery("div.menu").getTupleOfClassNames();
```

that will return an array of objects in the following manner:

```
[
    [div.menu.row1, div.menu.row1, div.menu.row1],
    [div.menu.row2, div.menu.row2],
    [div.menu.row3]
]
```

Is there something similar in jQuery to perform the described task above?

### Edit I

- I asked trying to see, if there was any other way to perform this task without the use of nested loops.
- I know this sounds like a very specific task and it's crazy to think that such process should be added in jQuery base API. (Just tring to find a clever way of doing this)

Comment: I doubt it, but it can easily be implemented.

Comment: Have you made any efforts, or were you just planning to ask us to recommend a tool, or do all the work?

Comment: And why would you need something like that, what's the use case? It sounds a lot like an X/Y problem ?

Comment: Please look at the update on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you wanted:

http://jsfiddle.net/aybc58Lo/

```js
$.fn.getTupleOfClassNames = function () {
    var items = {};
    var array = [];
    var row;

    this.each( function() {
        row = $(this).attr( 'class' ).split( ' ' )[1];
        if( !items[row] ) items[row] = [];
        items[row][items[row].length] = $(this);
    });

    $.each( items, function() {
        array[array.length] = this;
    });
    
    return array;
};

console.log($("div.menu").getTupleOfClassNames());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu row1"></div>
<div class="menu row1"></div>
<div class="menu row1"></div>
<div class="menu row2"></div>
<div class="menu row2"></div>
<div class="menu row3"></div>
```

I saw the other answers, but they're not in the form that you wanted to have.
My results are now:

```
[
    [jQueryObject, jQueryObject, jQueryObject],
    [jQueryObject, jQueryObject],
    [jQueryObject]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a very similar algorithm [here on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVVNWz). Using an object right off makes more sense as objects are key-value pairs(the key being the unique class), but the object could be transferred to an array of arrays by iterating over the outputted object.

```
$.fn.getTupleOfClassNames = function(){
  var retObj = {};
  this.each(function(i, e){
    if(!retObj[e.className]){
      retObj[e.className] = [];
    }
    retObj[e.className].push(e);
  });
  return retObj;
};

var retObj = $("div.menu").getTupleOfClassNames();
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
$.fn.getTupleOfClassNames = function () {
    var rows = [];
    this.each(function(i, el) {
          if ($(this).is('[class*="row"]')) {
              //get row class
              var c = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
              return v.indexOf('row') === 0;
          }).join();

          if(typeof rows[c] === 'undefined') {
               rows[c] = [];
          }
          rows[c].push($(this));
       }
    });
    return rows;
};

var tuple = $("div.menu").getTupleOfClassNames();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vorfr4bx/2/)